# Spring boot - injected map of repositories null in tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection

In my `@RestController` I am injecting a Map of `@Repositories` that all extend from `DataBaseRepository`. See constructor:

```
@Autowired
public DatasetController(Map<String, DataBaseRepository<?, ?>> reps) {
    this.repositories = reps;
}
```

This works like a charm in normal application, however this is not the case once I try to create a unit test for it (Mocks using Mockito):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DatasetControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private DailyTAVGRepository dailyTAVGRepository; // This extends from DataBaseRepository

    @InjectMocks
    private DatasetController datasetController;

    ...
}
```

In my tests `this.repositories` in `DatasetController` is **null**

What am I doing wrong or is this not possible in Unit Tests?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The constructor parameter expects a Map rather than a repository directly, so you could try creating a map with your mock and creating the object manually = `DatasetController datasetController = new DatasetController(yourMapContainingMocks)`

Comment: The good thin about your `DatasetController` is that it have an constructor. So you can build it manualy in your tests, instead of triing using auto-configuration.

Comment: @EamonScullion in real application I am never providing/constructing this map. It is created automatically by java dependency injection. String is Classname and DataBaseRepository is the appropriate Repository for this Classname. Why does it work in Application but not in Tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Before` to create your controller and then have mockito inject mocks for you.

```
@Before
public void init() {
    Map<String, DataBaseRepository> repos = new HashMap<>(); //you can leave this empty or add in a bunch of mocks of your own
    datasetController = spy(new DatasetController(repos));
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    //add your mocked repos to the repos map as needed after mocks are initialized
}
```

Comment: So there is no option to have that map automatically created and autowired in tests? in real application I am never providing/constructing this map. It is created automatically by java dependency injection. String is Classname and DataBaseRepository is the appropriate Repository for this Classname.
Why does it work in Application but not in Tests?

Comment: 1. There is an option. However, that violates the constraint of a unit test, which should not bring up a Spring Application instance and other services. 2. It works in Application because the Application is a Spring Application. If you want to use Spring into your tests you would use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and provide a spring configuration specifically for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly instantiate your DatasetController with a Map of DailyTAVGRepositories.

```
DatasetController datasetController = new DatasetController(mapWithRepositories);
```

You could also try to autowire the DailyTAVGRepository instead of Mocking it.